# I get a compile time error when accessing an ArrayList with a new method

Tags: java, class, object, methods, arraylist

I am attempting to access an `ArrayList` that was created in a different method within the same class. The scanner method pulls in data from a text file. The text file data appears this way: 123 12 1 43, with line breaks...

Currently, my method works to pull in the data, but does not compile after that method ends. I originally had the entire code within the same method and it worked fine. But I'd like to return the largest value by creating a new method within this class, and then create a `tester` class that will access this new method. Here is my existing code. Or if there is a better solution. I'm all ears.

```
public class DataAnalyzer {

public DataAnalyzer(File data) throws FileNotFoundException
{

        List<Integer> rawFileData = new ArrayList<>();
        FileReader file = new FileReader("info.txt");
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(file)) {
            while(in.hasNext())
            {
                rawFileData.add(in.nextInt());
            }
        }
}

public int getLargest(rawFileData){
     int largest = rawFileData.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < rawFileData.size(); i++){
            if (rawFileData.get(i) > largest)
            {
                largest = rawFileData.get(i);
            }
        }

        for (Integer element : rawFileData){
            if (element == largest)
            {
                System.out.print("This is the Largest Value: ");
                System.out.print(element);
            }
        }

    }      
}
```

Comment: `public int getLargest(rawFileData)` ? where is the `Type` ?

Comment: Anything wrong with [`Collections.max`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-)? You need to read some basic Java tutorials on how to define methods - your constructor has type parameter for the input variable; where is the type parameter for your method?

Comment: I am fairly new to Java and am learning more about objects and writing methods to access.  So I'm not sure if I'm not following some of your comments.

Comment: Style note:  You call `rawFileData.get(i)` from within `getLargest()`.  That's something you would only want to do if rawFileData refers to an `ArrayList`.  OK, it _does_ refer to an ArrayList in this example, but if the code _depends_ on rawFileData to refer to an ArrayList, then it should be _declared_ as an ArrayList, and not just a `List`.  This would matter in a large, evolving program where some other programmer might change the constructor to make some other kind of List, not realizing that the kind of List was important.

Comment: _I am receiving a compile time error_ is about as unhelpful a piece of information as you could give. The only thing more unhelpful would be _I am receiving an error_. Further, you posted a question and it was answered. Completely changing the question and hoping for new answers not only is a futile exercise but also invalidates all the answers already given - thereby making the question useless to future readers. I have reverted your question. If you want to ask another question, **ask another question**.

Answer (score 4):

Your main issue is with your method declaration. It needs a type parameter:

```
public int getLargest(List<Integer> rawFileData)
```

Note the `List<Integer>`.

Now, there is already a method for this in the [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) utility class. You would do well to look over that link in detail - there are many useful methods there. To get the highest element from a `Collection` of `Object`s that have a natural order (such a `Integer`). For example

```
int largest = Collections.max(rawFileData)
```

So your method can be reduced to:

```
public int getLargest(List<Integer> rawFileData)
    return Collections.max(rawFileData);
}
```

You need to think over your logic much more carefully before you begin to write code, for example, your first loop is good:

```
    int largest = rawFileData.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < rawFileData.size(); i++){
        if (rawFileData.get(i) > largest)
        {
            largest = rawFileData.get(i);
        }
    }
```

You do exactly what any programmer would do. But then, instead of returning the `largest` when you find it, you for some reason loop again:

```
    for (Integer element : rawFileData){
        if (element == largest)
        {
            System.out.print("This is the Largest Value: ");
            System.out.print(element);
        }
    }
```

Ask yourself what does this do? You have a `List` of, say, apples. You look at each one and compare them - finding the largest apple. You now **have** the largest apple in the `List`. You then loop over the `List` again looking for an apple that matches the apple you have already found. Why do this?

Further, you never `return` from the method. Your method is declared as returning an `int`; but you never do.

Comment: Thanks, I've started reading the java docs link that you've shared.

Comment: So I can use this method to create a getMethod in the same class.  And then create a separate class to pull that getMethod and obtain the Collections.max(rawFileData) data?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: This is the what I'm attempting to do.

        public class DataAnalyzerTester {
         
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println("Enter your fileName: ");              
          }
                         
    public void printLargest(DataAnalyzer rawFileData)
    {
        rawFileData.getLargest();
        System.out.println(rawFileData.getLargest());
    }
    }

Comment: I'm not convinced that some unformatted and illegible code in a comment clarifies the question much. If you have another question please post another question - I consider this question closed.

Answer (score 0):

The missing type in your method definition is the problem here.

Change the method definition from

```
public int getLargest(rawFileData) {
    ....
}
```

to

```
public void getLargest(List<Integer> rawFileData) {
    ....
}
```

And the second for loop in the method is unnecessary. The largest integer is already stored in the variable "largest" and you can print it after the first for loop.